# Storing a pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, heap-memory

I'm trying to create a memory allocation system, and part of this involves storing integers at pointer locations to create a sort of header. I store a couple of integers, and then two pointers (with locations to the next and prev spots in memory).

Right now I'm trying to figure out if I can store the pointer at a location that I could later use as the original pointer.

```
int * header;
int * prev; 
int * next;
...
*(header+3) = prev; 
*(header+4) = next;
```

Then later...

```
headerfunction(*(header+4));
```

would perform an operation using the pointer to the 'next' location in memory.

(code for illustration only)

Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: fyi `*(header+4)` is `header[4]`

Comment: sounds like a doubly linked list

Comment: It is a doubly linked list! thanks ring0, that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do direct pointer manipulation. Structs were made to eliminate the need for you to do that directly.

Instead, do something a bit more like this:

```
 typedef struct 
 {
    size_t cbSize;
 } MyAwesomeHeapHeader;

 void* MyAwesomeMalloc(size_t cbSize)
 {
    MyAwesomeHeapHeader* header;
    void* internalAllocatorPtr;
    size_t cbAlloc;
    // TODO: Maybe I want a heap footer as well?

    // TODO: I should really check the following for an integer overflow:
    cbAlloc = sizeof(MyAwesomeHeapHeader) + cbSize; 
    internalAllocatorPtr = MyAwesomeRawAllocator(cbAlloc);
    // TODO: Check for null

    header = (MyAwesomeHeapHeader*)internalAllocatorPtr;
    header->heapSize = cbSize;
    // TODO: other fields here.

    return (uint8_t*)(internalAllocatorPtr) + sizeof(MyAwesomeHeapHeader);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What-ever you are doing is not safe because you are trying to write a memory location which is not pointed by header as `*(header+3)` it will try to write to some other memory location 12 byte far from header pointer & if this newly memory is held by another variable then it will cause problem.

You can do as first of all allocating a big memory & then the start address will give you the source of your memory in which you can use some starting bytes or memory for controlling other parts of the remaining memory with the help of structures.

Comment: Sorry, I guess it isn't clear, but all of this memory has been allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Akp is correct, just looking at what you are trying to accomplish in your code segment, if you are trying to store integer pointers in header, header should be defined as such:

```
int **header;
```

and then memory should be allocated for it.

With regards to the actual memory allocation, if on a Unix machine, you should look into the brk() syscall.

Answer (score 0):

You are building a memory allocation system, and thus we assume you have a trunk of memory somewhere you can use freely to manage allocations and freeings.

As per your question, the `header` pointer is allocated in the `heap` memory (by the compiler and libraries) - and you may wonder if it is safe to use that memory since *you* are allocating memory. It depends on your system, and if there is another (system) memory allocation management.

But what you could do is

```
main() {
  void *header;
  void *prev;
  void *next;

   manage_memory_allocations(&header, &prev, &next); // never returns

}
```

In this case, the pointers are created on the stack - so the allocation depends on the memory where the processor stack points to.

Note the "never returns" as the memory is "freed" as soon as *main* ends.